# Deriving the probability of an event from limited trial data

Tags: probability

I have a stochastic event (say a weighted coin toss) that produces a positive outcome (heads) according to some unknown probability $P$.

Given $N$ total events (coin tosses) and n positive outcomes (heads), how can I measure the likelihood that $\frac nN$ is a good approximation of $P$?

Obviously, as $N$ grows, it becomes more likely than $\frac nN$ is close to the value $P$, but how can this convergence be described mathematically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I realise this isn't a full answer, the convergence you discuss is guaranteed by the weak and strong laws of large numbers. You might also be interested in Chebychev's inequality, which would say $$\mathbb{P}(|n/N - p| > \alpha) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha^2}$$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of your estimator, $n/N$. Finally the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) proves that as $N \to \infty$ the estimator becomes normally distributed about $p$ with variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem of *confidence intervals* in statistics.  Your question is about the original problem of that type, the  "confidence interval for a proportion in binomial sampling" (wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval )

The asymptotic theory, when $Np(1-p)$ is very large, is described by the Central Limit Theorem, which says that $n = pN + A\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$ where the probability distribution of $A$ is the famous Gaussian (normal, "bell shaped") curve.  Qualitatively, fluctuations of $n$ around the expected value are usually within a small factor of $\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$.

For limited data, the story is more complicated, with no perfect solution, many proposals, and a large literature.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki on [convergence of random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) is what you probably want to read. It discusses various forms of convergence and in particular [convergence in probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) and [almost sure convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence) are what you need to take a look at.